# Collect only the 1st level of href in a webpage using Python

Tags: python, html

I need to retrieve only the 1st level in a href of a website. For example: http://www.example.com/ is the website that I need to open and read.I opened the page and collected the href's and I obtained all the links like /company/organization, /company/globallocations, /company/newsroom, /contact, /sitemap and so on.

Below is the python code.

```
req = urllib2.Request(domain)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(response,'lxml')
for link in soup1.find_all('a',href = True):
     print link['href']
```

My desired output is,

/company, /contact, /sitemap for the website www.example.com

Kindly help and suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The **first level** concept is not clear, if you believe **href** links with one `/` is a first level, just simply count how many `/` in the **href** text, and decide keep it or drop it.

If we consider the web page point of view, all links in the home page, should be considered as **first level**. In this case, you may need to create a level counter to count how many levels / how deep your crawler goes into, and stop at certain level.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Zhong Dai. I meant the first level to be the link with one  ** / **. Is it possible to collect likewise ? Collect www.example.com/company instead of www.company.com/company/organization.

Comment: As I said, if you are sure the rule is such simple, just remove the last **/something**. This is easy to be done in Python, you can even use the `os.path.dirname(url)` to get the first part without **/something**.